# redirect based on url match

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I can't get a certain URL to redirect using mod rewrite. I am getting more basic rewriting happening so this is functioning as far as that goes so there is a problem with my URL.

I tried the string here and it showed the patter works..

http://regexpal.com/

testing the following

```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^landed.at/component/jreviews/search-results/criteria:5/query:any/jr_country:sri-lanka/order:rdate$
   RewriteRule (.*) http://landed.at/itworked [L,R=301]
```

I would like in fact to pull the criteria:5 and jr_country:sri-lanka out to make my variables 
so my url would become

http://landed.at/tours/sri-lanka - tours if criteria:5 and sri-lanka from the jr_country

I'm getting no where fast with regex and why doesn't my basic search match happen? according to regexpal it should find the condition and do the rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

You have included a full path including slashes, but you are only testing it against the `HTTP_HOST` which will be just `landed.at`. Did you mean to use `REQUEST_URI`? (That would have to include the `http://` also.)

I'd suggest this can probably be done more cleanly with plain old redirects. Don't drag the Swiss Army Chainsaw that is mod_rewrite into the game until you really need it. eg:

```
Redirect permanent /component/jreviews/search-results/criteria:5/query:any/jr_country:sri-lanka/order:rdate http://landed.at/itworked
```

Comment: Hi yes it could I was hoping to do this for every single country so wanted the 2 variables to dynamic make all my 173 odd countries working nicely.